# How select a row values to be column names of another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i'm new to SQl. I was wondering how i accomplish this task.
I have a department table and i want search if  'Math' is in any rows or columns in the table. If there a row with 'Math' i want to create a new table and set the entire row the be the column names of the new table.

[image]

So my new table will have '1004' and 'Math' as the new columns name.

Comment: You would need dynamic SQL for this, I strongly suggest you don't got down that path if you are new to SQL. What is the problem you are *really* trying to solve here?

Comment: Basically set any row where 'Math' is to be the column names of the new table so '1004 ' and 'Math 'instead of 'DepartmentId' and 'DepartmentName' @Larnu

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question. I want to know what the problem you are *really* trying to solve is; not the problem you say you want to solve here. This, very likely, is what we know as a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Anywhere in this table where there's a row with 'Math', i want to create a new table and set that row the be the column name of the new  table. That's basibally the problem i'm trying to solve. @Larnu

Comment: *"Anywhere in this table where there's a row with 'Math',*" so there's multiple rows with the value `'Math'` for department name? What are all of these tables going to be called then? Why do you want a denormalised approach?

Comment: So, Every time we get a new table in SQL, there are rows above the one that is actually the row that contains the columns names. Every time the row containing the column names change, so sometimes they are row 4 or 7, so we are tying to write a program that can detect which row contains the columns names. @Larnu

Comment: We're definitely missing context here. Best I can suggest, rethink your design and look into an normalised approach. Having multiple "math" tables, with different named columns is going to be very difficult to work with, and likely require dynamic SQL; you'll very likely end up introducing security vulnerabilities, as (as you stated) you're new to SQL and don't know what you're doing.

Comment: We are not going to have different math table. We will have a new table with a new name, but the row where 'Math' exist will be the column name of the new table.  So for instance, we will have table name 'XYZ' with  '1004' and 'Math' as the column names @Larnu

Comment: I think the point Larnu is trying to make is that while we don't understand what your database is supposed to do, most people think it is a bad idea to design databases that work like you are describing. If you elaborate on why you want a new table with these column names, and what you are trying to accomplish with your database, someone might be able to suggest a method of accomplishing that using industry standard means.

Answer (score 0):

I've said this is the comments, and I'm going to repeat myself, this look and sounds like a design flaw. As you are forcing yourself down a dynamic solution, then I suspect you are going to end up needing dynamic SQL to query the tables, and as someone who is new to SQL, that is a fatal mistake; you are very likely going to implement (large) security vulnerabilities into your system.

But, yes, you can do this. Note, however, this is untested and is pseudo-SQL as you don't define where the table's name comes from, nor what the data types for the columns will be. As a result you need to complete this, but it *should* get you on the right path:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'CREATE TABLE dbo.' + QUOTENAME({Your Table name}) + N' (' + @CRLF +
           (SELECT N'    ' + QUOTENAME(DepartmentID) + {Required Data Type} + N',' + @CRLF +
                   N'    ' + QUOTENAME(DepartmentName) + {Required Data Type} + N'' + @CRLF +
                   N');'
            FROM dbo.YourTable
            WHERE DepartmentID = 1004);

--PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

If you get stuck, use your best friend; it is up to you to understand this and if you don't, don't use it (but then, I've already suggested this multiple times).

Comment: Thank you @Larnu. But, i'm getting this error when i run the code 'Incorrect syntax near '}'.

Comment: Well you need to fix the Pseudo-SQL first, @Ricky . That error contains a right brace (`}`), so you've left at least some in there.

Comment: i'm just putting the data type int inside 'Required Data Type'. So + {int} +....... @Larnu

Comment: Braces aren't part of T-SQL @Ricky, I've used them to identify what you need to replace with the appropriate values. For example `{Required Data Type}` might `N'int'` or `N'varchar(20)'`, I don't know. Again, *you* need to take the time to under the solution here, and I couldn't complete it because you didn't give all the details.

Comment: I probably use the wrong table to show the example. So, the basic idea is that i to change the column names of the table. So instead of 'DepartmentId' and 'DepartmentName', I want to search in the table find a row with lets 'Math', and set the column names of the table to be the row where I find 'Math'. So, the final result will be a new table XYZ based on the initial table Departments, but with '1004' and 'Math' instead of 'DepartmentId' and 'DepartmentName. @Larnu

Comment: The above creates that table, @Ricky, as you stated you wanted. But, like I mentioned as well, I am pretty sure you have a design flaw. As you can't/won't tell us the true goal, I can't answer that, so I've answered the question asked; but it's up to you to implement it. We'll leave it at that.

Comment: You're right, it did create a new table. But it creates a new table with '[DepartmentId]' and '[DepartmentName]' as the column names, but I wanted it to create a new table with '1004' and 'Math' as the column names @Larnu

Comment: No it doesn't, @Ricky . It'll used the values of the columns, not the column names. Whatever it is you've done, you've implemented the solution wrong. You'll need to use your best friend to help you. With respect, [so] is not a free coding service nor a a consultation service; I've answered the question with the information provided. The rest is up to you now. Good luck.